# WordPress SQL Query on wp_usermeta table with wp_users table to get multiple meta_key meta_value pairs

Tags: sql, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to run a query in phpmyadmin that joins wp_users with wp_usermeta on the user_id to ID. I have the below so far.

```
SELECT
 wp_users.ID AS 'User ID',
 wp_users.display_name AS 'Name',
 meta_value AS 'Representative'
FROM wp_usermeta JOIN wp_users ON wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID
WHERE `meta_key` = 'representative' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY wp_users.ID
```

This works (or worked) but I am not sure it is the correct to accomplish this. I need 8 different meta_key/meta_value pairs I just don't know how to add them....

If you need more information I am happy to supply it...

Answer (score 1):

If you just looking to get value based on different keys, you can do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT u.ID, u.display_name, um.meta_value, um.meta_key
 FROM wp_usermeta AS um
 JOIN wp_users AS u
 ON um.user_id = u.ID
 WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%%'
) AS meta
WHERE `meta_key` = 'key1' OR `meta_key` = 'key2' OR `meta_key` = 'key3';
```

If this is working, you can add aliases after making sure you code works.

Comment: This looks like the right track. I seriously need to study sql more...I will let you know.

Comment: Okay this is close. I appreciate this, I was on the right path just confused. How would I be able to put the meta_keys into a column and have meta_values fill that column

Like I had before:

SELECT
 wp_users.ID AS 'User ID',
 wp_users.display_name AS 'Name',
 meta_value AS 'Representative' -> (This created a Representative column with the user reps as its values)
FROM wp_usermeta JOIN wp_users ON wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID
WHERE `meta_key` = 'representative' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%%'
Or point me in the right direction....

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is built on mySQL and php, so I see no reason not to. Will often be faster when have lots of absraction.

```
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ...");
print_r($result);
```

It should be possible to use this too I would think:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

View:

```
CREATE VIEW aviw_UserMetadata
AS
SELECT
 wp_users.ID AS 'User ID',
 wp_users.display_name AS 'Name',
 meta_value AS 'Representative'
FROM wp_usermeta 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID
WHERE `meta_key` = 'representative' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%%'
```

Comment: Well, no. It has to be outside wordpress. I need it as almost a view in phpmyadmin.  That is very fast.

Comment: Not sure why you are using LIKE '%%', but the view is perfect